# mysql query using filesort and temp without any order by and group by clause

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to tune the below query.

```
SELECT jsondata_c,
       id_c 
FROM accounts 
LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm 
ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  
WHERE ispropagated_c = 0 
AND deleted=0 
AND jsondata_c is not null  
ORDER BY accounts.date_modified DESC LIMIT 5
```

Its execution plan is as below

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: accounts_cstm
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY,id_c
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1325982
     filtered: 9.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: accounts
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_accnt_id_del,idx_accnt_assigned_del
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 108
          ref: oasyscrm.accounts_cstm.id_c
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I am not sure why query using filesort and temp without any order by and group by clause pertaining to accounts_cstm table.
Please suggest the ways to tune this query as it is taking around 1 min to execute.

Comment: You'll need to tell us which columns in your `where` clause are from which table, so we can tell you which index you need exactly, but in general, any index that is able to use `date_modified` should work, e.g. simply the index `date_modified` (if MySQL doesn't use it, try `straight_join` instead of `left join` here).

Comment: Columns jsondata_c,id_c, ispropagated_c are from table accounts_cstm.

Columns  deleted,date_modified are from accounts table.

Comment: I tried creating index on date_modified  column of account table but optimizer is not using it.

Comment: The best index would be `(deleted, date_modified)`, but unless you have *a lot* of undeleted data, an index on date_modified should just work fine. Can you check/verify that you have an index that starts with `id_c`? I was assuming it is the primary key, but if it is not (and you do not have another index for it), it would explain that behaviour.

Comment: i even tried creating index on (deleted, date_modified) but no luck :(

Comment: yes,we have index on id_c column

Comment: As I said, you could try to replace the `left join` with a `straight_join` (as it is no `left join` anyway). Then I guess MySQL would have no option than to do it right (if not: post your table definitions and the new explain plan). Not exactly sure why it doesn't do it right now.

Comment: i tried using straight_join and there is a significant improvement in the performance.I have given my suggestion to application team.Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Which columns are in which tables???